# how to add headers to uri in Android-Universal-Image-Loader library?

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader#useful-info how to add headers to while using this Android-Universal-Image-Loader library? Do this library have any kind function to attach   the headers with url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look here - https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/issues/340
You can pass custom headers for every task through `extra`. Or you can simply set them in `ImageDownloader`.

Comment: extra() is not working thing. It is just crashing with FileNotFound exception. Url and headers are right coz it provide right output in rest client.